Cannot resolve symbol 'AndroidSchedulers' in ViewModel - Java + Android Jetpack + Dagger2
I cannot, in any way, in my project, recognize the import of 'AndroidSchedulers'. I'm using the following imports (NOTE: IN MY PROJECT I USE THE VERSION CATALOG):
in my APP's build.gradle:
 implementation libs.io.reactivex.rxjava3
 implementation libs.io.reactivex.rxandroid

in libs.versions.toml:

refrofit = "2.9.0"
rxJava = "3.0.0"
rxAndroid = "2.1.0"

 retrofit-adapter-rxjava3 = { group = "com.squareup.retrofit2", name = "adapter-rxjava3", version.ref = "refrofit" }
 io-reactivex-rxjava3 = { group = "io.reactivex.rxjava3", name = "rxjava", version.ref = "rxJava" }
 io-reactivex-rxandroid = { group = "io.reactivex.rxjava3", name = "rxandroid", version.ref = "rxAndroid" }

In my view-model I am trying to use the
 .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())

I reference the import of 'AndroidSchedulers':
 import io.reactivex.rxjava3.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers;

However, the IDE still says that it is not possible to resolve this 'AndroidSchedulers' reference
Below is a printout of my view-model to illustrate:[
What dependencies do I still need to add to the project to be able to work with 'AndroidSchedulers'?
Can you help me with this problem?
I tried to implement it as I know it, but I was unable to obtain the expected result, in this context of the question.
